# Anyone tried installation of Ubuntu in Hp 14-al106ne laptop

Tags: system-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu on Hp 14-al106ne laptop . The installation freezes either at language selection or the screen after. disable secure boot in bios, nomodeset  , everything tried Some how its compete installation process after that one's when log on time its will freeze again. Also i try all flavors of linux distro but still face same issue.

Comment: What are hardware specs?

Comment: HP Pavilion - 14-al106ne
Intel® Core™ i5-7200U (2.5 GHz, up to 3.1 GHz, 3 MB cache, 2 cores)
8 GB DDR4-2133 SDRAM (1 x 8 GB)
NVIDIA® GeForce® 940MX
1 TB

Comment: These are not specs, but a model name